# Conways game - accessing out of bound data

Tags: c, conways-game-of-life

This is my Conway's Game of Life C code.

Function **newgen** checks neighboring cells, all eight of them, even if cell is on the edge of the matrix. How can I change it in a way that won't results in accessing out of bound data, and undefined behavior?

Also I have this error:

```
1   IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int *"
```

The code is:

```
void copy() {
  int i, j;
  for (i = j = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
    for (; j < WIDTH; j++) {
      gb2[i][j] = gb[i][j];
    }
  }
}

void init() {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
    gb [i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*WIDTH);
    gb2[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*WIDTH);
  }
  for (i = 0 ; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
    for (j = 0 ; j < WIDTH; j++) {
      gb [i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
  gb[0][0] = 1;
  gb[0][1] = 1;
  gb[1][0] = 1;
  gb[1][1] = 1;
  copy();
}
```

...
    int main() {
      int i;
      init();
      newgen();
      printg();
      for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        free(gb[i]);
        free(gb2[i]);
      }
    }

Comment: Could you tell us what is the issue with your program?  For the warning, you get it because you are compiling with a C++ compiler: in C this is fine, in C++ cast the `malloc` return's value to `int *`.

Comment: In `newgen()` `j-1` is out of bounds, is that what you mean to fix? Also you are missing `free`ing of `gb2` array of pointers ... AFAIK `free`ing just before the program exits is not much of a consequence

Comment: another.anon.coward, where i miss free? gb2? can you please explain more?

Comment: You are `malloc`ing in `init()` for `gb2[]` in a loop for which there is no corresponding `free` call anywhere in the posted code like you have to `gb[]` in the `for` loop before main returns And for out of bound maybe you need a `j>0` check for `j-1` access?

Comment: ouah, i'm using c and not c++

Comment: so what you say - put free(gb2[i]); int the main? is that the way to solve it? why j-1?

Comment: what about the  1 IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int *" ? i use c and not c++

Comment: Although you *can* [skip](http://c-faq.com/malloc/freeb4exit.html) just before return, but it is good practice to `free`. You need to add `free(gb2[i]);` after `free(gb[i]);`. `j-1` because when j=0, j-1=-1, which is out of bounds of the array

Comment: so you mean that i need to change   for (j = 0 ; j < WIDTH; j++) to   for (j-1 = 0 ; j < WIDTH; j++) ? why? are we talking about the same init function?

Comment: You should edit your question to say what compiler you are using, in order to solve the Intellisense error. I guess MSVC but what version (2008, 2010)? What level (Express, Standard, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested the code below (and it is incomplete anyway) but you should loop over all the elements in your array and update the neighbour count. You can use a couple of loops that run over all the neighbouring cells and performs bounds checking as it goes.

You should also reset the neighbouring cell count when you start processing each cell.

```
void newgen()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
        {
            int n = 0;

            for (int test_y = i - 1; test_y <= (i + 1); ++test_y)
            {
                for (int test_x = j - 1; test_x <= (j + 1); ++test_x)
                {
                    if ((test_x != test_y) &&
                        (test_x >= 0) && (test_x < WIDTH) &&
                        (test_y >= 0) && (test_y < HEIGHT))
                    {
                        if (gb[test_y][test_x])
                        {
                            n++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            /* Process the n value here */
        }
    }
}
```

You could probably just have used static arrays instead of allocating along one dimension, or allocate along both dimensions. Currently it's a mixture of static and dynamic sizes which isn't a problem it just seems inconsistent.

Your Intellisense error sounds like Intellisense only handles C++ code, not C code, but that is only a guess. You can configure the compiler (I'm assuming MSVC here) to compile as C or C++ but perhaps Intellisense either does not have that option or it is configured separately.

Answer (score 1):

In `newgen()` you loop from 1 to HEIGHT - 2 for the rows, which avoids out of bounds access, but for the columns you loop from 0 to WIDTH - 2, so you have out of bounds access in every line that accesses j - 1, when you are in the first column. i.e.,

```
for (j = 0; j < WIDTH-1; j++) {
   if (gb[i][j+1]) n++;
   if (gb[i+1][j]) n++;
   if (gb[i+1][j+1]) n++;
   if (gb[i-1][j-1]) n++; // <- Here,
   if (gb[i][j-1]) n++;   // <- here,
   if (gb[i-1][j]) n++;
   if (gb[i+1][j-1]) n++; // <- ...and here.
   if (gb[i-1][j+1]) n++;
```

Begin with j equal to 1, not 0, when you begin the loop over columns:

```
for (j = 1; j < WIDTH-1; j++) {
```

Comment: I'd suggest looping over all elements in the array, but providing inner loops to replace the 8 checks with some built in bounds checking. That way you could update the cells along the edges, which starting from 1 won't do.

Comment: Martin,  i have updated the code according to your answer - do i need to use j=1 elsewhere to avoid the bounds ?

Comment: I second the opinion of @tinman, you need to loop from 0 to HEIGHT-1 & 0 to WIDTH-1, otherwise your results will be incorrect, so better add bound checks in the loops

Comment: can you please write the syntax of the bound check you say i should use? i do not understand what kind of bound check you mean cause i already try to avoid the bounds as you can see

Comment: I also agree with @tinman. My answer was simply to do with the columns what you seemed to want to do with the rows.

Answer (score 0):

The IntelliSense warning is because you are using Visual C++ and the warning would be appropriate in C++. (It's not so “intelli” when you are using C.) You can avoid the warning by casting the return value of `malloc` to `(int *)`, although [casting the return of `malloc` is not recommended in C](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html).

As for avoiding out of bounds access: do not access out of bounds. Some possible solutions include:

- Create a function to return the live/dead value of a singe cell, and check the bounds there, returning 0 if it's out of bounds. (Or you can wrap around the grid to the other side; this is nice if you want to animate, e.g., a [glider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glider_%28Conway%27s_Life%29) on a small grid.)
- Don't include the first or last row or column in your loop, instead treat those as special cases and don't access beyond the boundaries.
- Allocate two extra rows and columns, initialize them to zero, and then don't iterate over the last row or column (i.e., treat your active grid as [1..w][1..h] but allocate w+2 columns and h+2 rows). Then you don't need a special case for the edges, but use a small amount of extra memory.

Comment: @Blondy21 That's where you define the variables `gb` and `gb2`, when you assign to them from `malloc` you need to cast the return value in C++ (but not C, but IntelliSense assumes C++), i.e., `gb = (int *)malloc(…)`. In any case, you can probably just ignore this warning.